# Mathematica simplify conjugate expression

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, simplification

Is there a way to simplify this conjugate expression:

```
expr=d12*Conjugate[C1]*C2 + d12*Conjugate[C2]*C1 + d13*Conjugate[C1]*C3 + d13*Conjugate[C3]*C1
```

into something like:

```
2 d12 (Re[C1*Conjugate[C2]]) + 2 d13 (Re[C1*Conjugate[C3]])
```

And in general, how Mathematica determines one expression is simpler than another? Is there a way to add some personalized rules to its simplification process? For example, can we tell Mathematica that we prefer `2*Re[C1*Conjugate[C2]]` than `C1*Conjugate[C2]+C2*Conjugate[C1]` ? Thanks.

*Update*:

Thanks for the suggestions. `ComplexExpand` can expand it to real and imaginary part, but seems still can't simplify to the preferred form:

```
In: Simplify[ComplexExpand[expr, {C1, C2, C3}]]
Out: 2 (Im[C1] (d12 Im[C2] + d13 Im[C3]) + Re[C1] (d12 Re[C2] + d13 Re[C3]))
```

I tried the TransformationFunctions function like this but it doesn't work:

```
In: t = # /. (Im[C1] Im[C2] + Re[C1] Re[C2] -> 1/2 Re[C1\[Conjugate] C2]) &;    
In: Simplify[ComplexExpand[expr, {C1, C2, C3}], TransformationFunctions -> {Automatic, t}]
Out: 2 (Im[C1] (d12 Im[C2] + d13 Im[C3]) + Re[C1] (d12 Re[C2] + d13 Re[C3]))
```

Am I doing the wrong way? Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried `ComplexExpand[]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually it simplifies to smaller expression

```
expr=d12*Conjugate[C1]*C2+d12*Conjugate[C2]*C1+d13*Conjugate[C1]*C3 + 
     d13*Conjugate[C3]*C1;
Simplify[ComplexExpand[expr]]
```

gives

```
2 C1 (C2 d12 + C3 d13)
```

*how Mathematica determines one expression is simpler than another? Is there a way to add some personalized rules to its simplification process*

You can use the `ComplexityFunction` option to `Simplify`. The default is `Automatic` and I think this uses Leaf count to decide. You can also use the `TransformationFunctions` option to `Simplify` to provide your own functions to apply. See help.

http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ComplexityFunction.html

http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/TransformationFunctions.html

http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/LeafCount.html

Comment: Thanks. But `ComplexExpand[expr]` assumes all variables in expr are Real, here `C1 C2 C3` are complex. If use `Simplify[ComplexExpand[expr,{C1,C2,C3}]]` I get `2 (Im[C1] (d12 Im[C2] + d13 Im[C3]) + 
   Re[C1] (d12 Re[C2] + d13 Re[C3]))`. But it still not in the shape I prefer.